# can i modify APIs for my android application?

Tags: android, api

I am trying to develop an app for hotel booking. I need to know if I use other APIs. can I make edit/modify those APIs to fulfill my app purpose.

Comment: What does the license say for those API's?

Comment: Ok, I need to check those first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.